# Template references type deducion

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, rvalue-reference

I have a template function:

```
template<typename T>
void doSomething(T& value) {
    // doSomething here
}
```

All is ok, but passing r-value references:

```
doSomething(getTempVal());
```

Producing `no matching function for call` error, because particular instantiated function template `expects an l-value for 1st argument`. Is there any workarounds to allow template function taking both lvalue and rvalue references without adding new template?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, just use `&&` instead of `&`.

It may seem odd, because you might think that this would disallow calling it with lvalues, but actually, if `T` is itself an lvalue reference type, then `T &&` is just `T`: it doesn't become an rvalue reference type.

In other words,

```
template <typename T>
void f(T &&);

int main() {
  int k = 1;
  f(k); // okay: calls f<int&>
  f(2); // okay: calls f<int>
}
```

Note that `T` can be deduced as a reference type, and the function body will need to be made to handle that.

Comment: Very nice but, unfortunately it break function internal assert even for embedded types: `static_assert(std::is_pod<T>::value, "T must be POD");`

Comment: @vard Then `T` probably isn't a POD. It's probably a reference to a POD. You can use `typename std::remove_reference<T>::type` to get the referenced type.

Comment: @vard you don't show that code. How are we gonna know anything about it?

Comment: @vard Read about perfect forwarding ane how it works. The problem is that in the lvalue case T is a reference type.

Comment: @sehe How can i foresee which internal line of 15 function lines will cause an issue for particular workaround? In fact this clarification should be another question

Comment: @vard Indeed. So, that's why I asked the rhetorical :)